# Why does HighCharts reverse the order of my series?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm using HighCharts to render a stacked percentage horizontal bar chart, and it works great except HighCharts reverses the order of my series data by default.

http://jsfiddle.net/U8nZ6/

As you can see in the demo, despite $20k being the first row of the data1/data2 array, it's the last chunk of each bar (all the way on the right). I'd like this to be in order, so I tried a couple things:

1) Render the chart with the array `.reverse()`d. You can enable those lines on the above demo to see that the result of that is that colors don't line up since there are a different number of records in each chart, so this won't work (and shouldn't be the only way to do this, I'm sure)

2) Use `xAxis.reversed = true`. This puts it in the right order with the colors matching, but then the legend is reversed (100% to 0%) and it animates right-to-left.

Is there another way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, assuming there's no alternative, here's what I went with in case anyone stumbles upon this through Google:

Using option 2 described above (reversing the axis), I simply modified the labels via the formatter to be the inverse.

In my case, since it's percentage (0-100), I simply put:

`labels: { formatter: function() { return Math.abs(this.value - 100) } }`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there's an option called reverseStacks (http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.reversedStacks) that defaults to true for stacked charts. You might want to set this to false in your code.

I noticed that your JSFiddle specifically requests Highcharts version 2.3.5, in which this option is presumably not there.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. After trying different options I ended up setting series index before rendering the chart. Generic code:

```
if (options.chart.type === 'bar') {

    for (var i = 0; i < options.series.length; i++) {
        options.series[i].index = options.series.length - 1 - i;
        options.series[i].legendIndex = i;
    }
}
```

Updated jsFiddle for your example: http://jsfiddle.net/U8nZ6/23/

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still looking for this.  I used **reversed:true** in my legend.

```
legend: {
            align: 'right',
            x: -30,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 25,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
            borderColor: '#CCC',
            borderWidth: 1,
            shadow: false,
            reversed: true // right here!
        }
```